# How do I save a movie to a custom named album in swift

Tags: swift, ios8, alassetslibrary

in objective C one could save a video to a custom named photo album using code similar to what follows

```
-(void)saveImage:(UIImage*)image
         toAlbum:(NSString*)albumName
withCompletionBlock:(SaveImageCompletion)completionBlock;
```

I can't figure out how to do this ins swift, when I look at the definition of ALAssetsLibrary I don't see any function call toAlum or savedImage. I can't seem to figure this out?

Comment: It seems they change a little bit ->  [writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock:](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ALAssetsLibrary/writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock:)

Comment: I saw that as well as writeVideoSavedPhotosAlbum: but how do you specify that name of the album that you want to use?

Comment: It seems this API changed a lot for iOS 8 and you have no more option than read the documentation. This comes from Apple: IMPORTANT

In iOS 8.0 and later, use the Photos framework instead of the Assets Library framework. The Photos framework provides more features and better performance for working with a user’s photo library. See [Photos Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/Photos_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014408)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code I used

```
var albumFound : Bool = false
var assetCollection: PHAssetCollection!
var photosAsset: PHFetchResult!
var assetThumbnailSize:CGSize!

// Create the album if does not exist (in viewDidLoad)
      if let first_Obj:AnyObject = collection.firstObject{
                //found the album
                self.albumFound = true
                self.assetCollection = collection.firstObject as PHAssetCollection
            }else{
                //Album placeholder for the asset collection, used to reference collection in completion handler
                var albumPlaceholder:PHObjectPlaceholder!
                //create the folder
                NSLog("\nFolder \"%@\" does not exist\nCreating now...", albumName)
                PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges({
                    let request = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetCollectionWithTitle(albumName)
                    albumPlaceholder = request.placeholderForCreatedAssetCollection
                    },
                    completionHandler: {(success:Bool, error:NSError!)in
                        NSLog("Creation of folder -> %@", (success ? "Success":"Error!"))
                        self.albumFound = (success ? true:false)
                        if(success){
                            let collection = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollectionsWithLocalIdentifiers([albumPlaceholder.localIdentifier], options: nil)
                            self.assetCollection = collection?.firstObject as PHAssetCollection
                        }
                })
            }



let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
            let myFilePath = bundle.pathForResource("highlight1", ofType: "mov")
            let videoURL:NSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(myFilePath!)!

            let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0), {
                PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges({
                    //let createAssetRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromImage
                    let createAssetRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideoAtFileURL(videoURL)
                    let assetPlaceholder = createAssetRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset
                    let albumChangeRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(forAssetCollection: self.assetCollection, assets: self.photosAsset)
                    albumChangeRequest.addAssets([assetPlaceholder])
                    }, completionHandler: {(success, error)in
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                            NSLog("Adding Image to Library -> %@", (success ? "Sucess":"Error!"))
                            //picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                        })
                })

            })
```

keep in mind what I'm doing is copying a file from my bundle into this album (pre populateing it with videos)

Comment: Without your post, I would've never realized that one has to create a placeholder when passing assets between PhotoLib and a collection on iOS. Thank you!

Comment: this `let albumChangeRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(forAssetCollection: self.assetCollection, assets: self.photosAsset)` cause error for accessing nil value